# Container view is not showing static table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uicontainerview

I have a container view which lies within a `UIViewController` and embeds a `UITableViewController` that has static cells. Although my constraints are fine, and the `UIView` for the Container View appears on the UI Debugger, the container doesn't display its contents. Here some photos of what I mean:

What's in the simulator
[image]

The storyboard
[image]

The debugger
[image]

Comment: did you set the delegate & datasource ?

Comment: Yes, they are both set to a UITableViewController called `RadiusSubView`

Comment: can you provide the code for RadiusSubView?

Comment: What kind of constraints did you set on the UITableView? Since it's scrollable it doesn't automatically take the height of your cells combined.

Comment: 'RadiusSubView' is empty. It's the standard swift file Xcode makes when you make a class file that subclasses 'UITableViewController'. The only constrains are on the container and the labels in the cells. Both of which I know work because if I set the storyboard entry point to the embedded table view, it looks normal.

Comment: @Cole, were you able to solve your problem? I have run into the same issue trying to embed a static table inside a container view, but it won't display. I would like to hear your solution or findings if any.

Comment: @BenS I had this issue quite some time ago but I think the fix was just to do away with the container view and implement it directly on the parent view controller. Sorry I couldn't give you a real answer.

Comment: @Cole, thanks for the reply. My issue ended up being that the `UITableViewController` that I had assigned to the `UITableView` had default delegate/datasource methods populated with 0 returning for number of sections and 0 returning for number of rows.. **FacePalm** moment.